# Spring Security with roles and permissions

Tags: java, spring-security

I'm trying to set up role-based Security with permissions. I'm trying to do this together with  Spring-Security.

I don't want to set up ACL as it seems it's an overkill for my requirements.

I just want to have simple permissions and roles as described in this [article](http://springinpractice.com/2010/10/27/quick-tip-spring-security-role-based-authorization-and-permissions/).
Unfortunately the article does not describe how to implement the given solution.

Has someone already tried this and can point me in the right direction? Maybe there is another blog entry that describes the implementation?

Thank you very much.

Comment: To all who arrive here, there is an article which solves exactly my problem. Please have a look at [this](http://slackspace.de/articles/roles-permissions-with-spring-security-3/)

Comment: I read that article and Im trying to implement that. Would you please tell me how did you implement that SpringSecurityDaoImpl  class? @PreAuthorize doesnt affect my urls at all! I have done exactly like the material in that article.

Comment: @sina You don't have to implement the `SpringSecurityDaoImpl` just extend `JdbcDaoImpl` as it is in the example. Make sure to look at the example code on github, which is referenced in the article.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To implement that, it seems that you have to:

1. Create your model (user, role, permissions) and a way to retrieve permissions for a given user;
2. Define your own  `org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager` and configure it (set its providers) to a custom `org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider`.
   This last one should return on its authenticate method a Authentication, which should be setted with the `org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority`, in your case, all the permissions for the given user.

The trick in that article is to have roles assigned to users, but, to set the permissions for those roles in the `Authentication.authorities` object.

For that I advise you to read the API, and see if you can extend some basic ProviderManager and AuthenticationProvider instead of implementing everything. I've done that with `org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider` setting a custom LdapAuthoritiesPopulator, that would retrieve the correct roles for the user.

Hope this time I got what you are looking for.
Good luck.

Comment: extend this one DaoAuthenticationProvider and give it a custom UserDetailsService, that should perform the permissions loading.

Answer (score 85):

I'm the author of the article in question.

No doubt there are multiple ways to do it, but the way I typically do it is to implement a custom `UserDetails` that knows about roles and permissions. `Role` and `Permission` are just custom classes that you write. (Nothing fancy--`Role` has a name and a set of `Permission` instances, and `Permission` has a name.) Then the `getAuthorities()` returns `GrantedAuthority` objects that look like this:

`PERM_CREATE_POST`, `PERM_UPDATE_POST`, `PERM_READ_POST`

instead of returning things like

`ROLE_USER`, `ROLE_MODERATOR`

The roles are still available if your `UserDetails` implementation has a `getRoles()` method. (I recommend having one.)

Ideally you assign roles to the user and the associated permissions are filled in automatically. This would involve having a custom `UserDetailsService` that knows how to perform that mapping, and all it has to do is source the mapping from the database. (See the article for the schema.)

Then you can define your authorization rules in terms of permissions instead of roles.

Comment: Hi, Could you please provide a practical solution of Custom User details as you detailed in that answer? thanks.

Comment: Hi, I implemented a application using Spring Security using a custom AuthenticationProvider and UserDetailsService classes. Now, I want use roles and permissions in my application. I am using now this: **@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")**, which uses handles only roles. How I expand this to handle the permissions. (More details here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23072619/implementation-of-roles-and-permissions-in-spring-security)

Answer (score 7):

This is the simplest way to do it. Allows for group authorities, as well as user authorities.

```
-- Postgres syntax

create table users (
  user_id serial primary key,
  enabled boolean not null default true,
  password text not null,
  username citext not null unique
);

create index on users (username);

create table groups (
  group_id serial primary key,
  name citext not null unique
);

create table authorities (
  authority_id serial primary key,
  authority citext not null unique
);

create table user_authorities (
  user_id int references users,
  authority_id int references authorities,
  primary key (user_id, authority_id)
);

create table group_users (
  group_id int references groups,
  user_id int referenecs users,
  primary key (group_id, user_id)
);

create table group_authorities (
  group_id int references groups,
  authority_id int references authorities,
  primary key (group_id, authority_id)
);
```

Then in META-INF/applicationContext-security.xml

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder" id="passwordEncoder" />

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>

        <jdbc-user-service
                data-source-ref="dataSource"

                users-by-username-query="select username, password, enabled from users where username=?"

                authorities-by-username-query="select users.username, authorities.authority from users join user_authorities using(user_id) join authorities using(authority_id) where users.username=?"

                group-authorities-by-username-query="select groups.id, groups.name, authorities.authority from users join group_users using(user_id) join groups using(group_id) join group_authorities using(group_id) join authorities using(authority_id) where users.username=?"

                />

          <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />

    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Comment: can you please add the simple data with respect to the table?

Answer (score 6):

The basic steps are:

1. Use a custom authentication provider

   ```
   <bean id="myAuthenticationProvider" class="myProviderImplementation" scope="singleton">
   ...
   </bean>
   ```
2. Make your custom provider return a custom `UserDetails` implementation. This `UserDetailsImpl` will have a `getAuthorities()` like this:

   ```
   public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
       List<GrantedAuthority> permissions = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
       for (GrantedAuthority role: roles) {
           permissions.addAll(getPermissionsIncludedInRole(role));
       }
       return permissions;
   }
   ```

Of course from here you could apply a lot of optimizations/customizations for your specific requirements.

Answer (score 2):

ACL was overkill for my requirements also.
I ended up creating a library similar to @Alexander's  to inject a `GrantedAuthority` list for Role->Permissions based on the role membership of a user.

For example, using a DB to hold the relationships -

```
@Autowired 
RolePermissionsRepository repository;

public void setup(){
  String roleName = "ROLE_ADMIN";
  List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
  permissions.add("CREATE");
  permissions.add("READ");
  permissions.add("UPDATE");
  permissions.add("DELETE");
  repository.save(new RolePermissions(roleName, permissions));
}
```

When an Authentication object is injected in the current security session, it will have the original roles/granted authorities.

This library provides 2 built-in integration points for Spring Security.
When the integration point is reached, the PermissionProvider is called to get the effective permissions for each role the user is a member of.
The distinct list of permissions are added as GrantedAuthority items in the Authentication object.

You can also implement a custom `PermissionProvider` to store the relationships in config for example.

A more complete explanation here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60251931/1308685

And the source code is here - 
https://github.com/savantly-net/spring-role-permissions

Answer (score 1):

Just for sake of completeness (maybe someone else won't have to implement it from scratch):

We've implemented our own small library, as everyone else. It's supposed to make things easier, so that our developers don't have to reimplement it each time. It would be great if spring security would provide support of rbac out of the box, as this approach is much better than the default permission based one.

Have a look at [Github](https://github.com/vsfexperts/rbac) (OSS, MIT license) to see if it suits your needs. It's basically only addressing the role <-> privileges mapping. The missing piece, you'll have to provide on your own is basically the user <-> roles mapping, e.g. by mapping groups (racf/ad groups) to roles (1:1) or by implementing an additional mapping. That one's different in each project, so it doesn't make sense to provide some implementation.

We've basically used this internally, so that we can start with rbac from the beginning. We can still replace it with some other implementation later on, if the application is growing, but it's important for us to get the setup right at the beginning.

If you don't use rbac, there's a good chance, that the permissions are scattered throughout the codebase and you'll have a hard time to extract/group those (into roles) later on.
The generated graphs do also help to reason about it/restructure it later on.

Answer (score 0):

After reading this [post](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-granted-authority-vs-role), from Baeldung. I found that the solution is pretty simple.

What I have done, is to add the role and permissions into the GrantedAuthority.
I was able to access both methods hasRole() and hasAuthority().