# Spring security permissions based access for api

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security, spring-rest

We have a solution implemented based on this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357579/spring-security-with-roles-and-permissions) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9029859/508214). Now we need to enhance this solution. Here is the use case.

There are various permissions like `CREATE_USER`, `CREATE_ORG` etc... But based on user roles we need to apply certain restrictions. For example `ROLE_ADMIN` as well as `ROLE_ORG_ADMIN` can create users. But `ROLE_ORG_ADMIN`can only create users with some specific permission (or `ROLE_ORG_ADMIN` should not be able to create a user with `ROLE_ADMIN` privileges)

1. `ROLE` is simply a group of permissions
2. User is associated with a role and on login `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.authorities` is set with permissions instead of `ROLE`

We have REST application with token based authentication.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users",
     method = RequestMethod.POST,
     produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Secured(AuthoritiesConstants.CREATE_USER)
public ResponseEntity<?> createUser(@RequestBody ...)
```

Now we have an admin interface where we control these restrictions from UI, in UI for creating user we do not display `ROLE_ADMIN` in select list for `ROLE_ORG_ADMIN`. We are going to expose api for third party. We are not sure how this can be done at api level.

```
POST /api/users
{
  "id": null,
  "login": "name",
  "firstName": "first",
  "lastName": "Last",
  "email": "first.last@email.com",
  "activated": true,
  "langKey": "en",
  "createdBy": null,
  "createdDate": null,
  "lastModifiedBy": null,
  "lastModifiedDate": null,
  "resetDate": null,
  "resetKey": null,
  "authorities": [
    "ROLE_ORG_ADMIN",
    "ROLE_ADMIN"
  ]
}
```

What we want to do is to restrict a user with role `ROLE_ORG_ADMIN` creating users with role `ROLE_ADMIN`. Both `ROLE_ORG_ADMIN` and `ROLE_ADMIN` has permission `CREATE_USER`. If the current user role is not `ROLE_ADMIN` api should respond with access denied when tried to create a user with role `ROLE_ADMIN`. Please help.

Comment: @willie-wheeler since you are the author of article i mentioned please review this question.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share two ways to handle this,
Option 1. How you are listing the available User_Roles to the user while creating the user? If  you are displaying all the user roles and allowing the user to select the respective role, then while listing the available user roles itself you can avoid listing the ROLE_ADMIN if the logged user is ROLE_ORG_ADMIN.

Option 2. If you don't like to handle it in  UI, then while creating the USER in the back end, you can through the exception if the logged in user ROLE_ORG_ADMIN tries to create the USER with ROLE_ADMIN. You can access the logged in user details through principle object.

Hope any one option can be implemented.

Comment: I have no issue in handling this in UI. I am already doing what you mentioned. I am trying to figure out how to control when I expose API's. Looking if there are any inbuilt spring way of doing this.