# Spring Security role-based authorisation issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, authorization

I have implemented spring security in my application.
It is stateless-token based authentication and username/password based authentication.

I have configured user authentication, but the role-based authorisation is not working.

A user who has `ROLE_USER` is able to access the controller method which has `ROLE_ADMIN`.

Here is the configuration.

```
@EnableWebSecurity 
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
@Configuration 
public class SpringSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    AuthenticationProvider passwordBasedAuthenticationProvider() {
        return new PasswordBasedAuthenticationProvider();
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticationProvider tokenBasedAuthenticationProvider(){
        return new TokenBasedAuthenticationProvider();
    }   

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {        
         web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/v1/public/**");
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http.
         csrf().disable().
         sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).
         and().
         authorizeRequests().
         anyRequest().authenticated().
         and().
         anonymous().disable();   
         http.addFilterBefore(new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(passwordBasedAuthenticationProvider()).
            authenticationProvider(tokenBasedAuthenticationProvider());
    }
}
```

---

**DOMAINS**

```
@Entity
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority  {
    private long id;    
    private String authority;
}

public class User implements UserDetails{
     private String username;
     private String passwordHash;
     private Role role;
}

@RestController 
public class TesController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/authController")
    @Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
    String test(){ return "I am secure for ROLE_ADMIN"}
}
```

---

What is incorrect about this configuration?

Comment: Nothing in your configuration actually mentions either `ROLE_USER` or `ROLE_ADMIN`. I'm only used to using the XML config. Where are roles supposed to be defined, so that `TesController` can actually pick them up?

Comment: If you change your `configure` method by adding `.antMatchers("/authController").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")` the situation is the same?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define at least the RoleHierarchie with something like this or whatever the configuration may look like in your case:

```
@Bean
public RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy() {
  RoleHierarchyImpl r = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
  r.setHierarchy("ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_STAFF");
  r.setHierarchy("ROLE_STAFF > ROLE_USER");
  r.setHierarchy("ROLE_DEVELOPER > ROLE_USER");
  r.setHierarchy("ROLE_USER > ROLE_GUEST"); 
  return r;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357579/spring-security-with-roles-and-permissions

Answer (score 0):

When you use @Secured, no need to add prefix ROLE_ just use this

```
@RestController 
public class TesController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/authController")
    @Secured("ADMIN")
    String test(){ return "I am secure for ROLE_ADMIN"}
}
```