# Writing Interceptor Filter for user Authentication

Tags: java, spring, authentication, handler, interceptor

Creating a simple filter for trivial web application.

- login
- register
- home
- feature

if the user has not logged in using the login name "admin", or tries to access the /home resource or /feature resource, they should be routed back to the login page.

However, it appears I am running into a redirect loop problem. What is the problem with this approach. I feel it is incorrect solution approach for such a requirement.

```
public class LoginInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("LoginInterceptor.class");

    // to be used checking session management for user.
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response,
                             Object handler) throws Exception {

        logger.log(Level.INFO, "[][][][][] +++ prehandle");


        if (request.getAttribute("username") != null) {
            if (request.getAttribute("username").equals("admin")) {
                return true;
            } else
                response.sendRedirect("/sessionmanagement/login");
            return false;
        } else if (request.getAttribute("username") == null & !request.getRequestURI().equals("/login")) {
            // return false and redirect to login.
            response.sendRedirect("/sessionmanagement/login");
            return false;
        }
        // return false and redirect to login.
        response.sendRedirect("/sessionmanagement/register");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: what's your url pattern for `LoginInterceptor`?

Comment: Add also if condition to check whether request URL contains  /sessionmanagement, which will help you to avoid looping.

Comment: /* is the url pattern for the interceptor

Comment: Arsen - how exactly do you mean ? /sessionmanagement is the root context of the application

Comment: Wild guess but instead of `getAttribute` you actually want to check `getParameter` (assuming you want to check the existence and value of a request parameter).

Answer (score 0):

if you are using spring you can use the spring security to do that, your user can have ROLES, so you won't be checking just against the username, https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/ here is a guide that you can go over it, it is a pretty straight forward , so your methods you have a annotation to check what is the authority of the user.

here another thing that can help you : [Spring Security with roles and permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357579/spring-security-with-roles-and-permissions)

http://www.journaldev.com/8748/spring-security-role-based-access-authorization-example

Comment: thank you for the information. i should have mentioned I am trying to do this without using spring security, for now.

Comment: Just one question, why would you do that ? is there any reason ?

Comment: yes so i can understand and implement the functionality myself.

Comment: ok, in this case you need to exclude the login page itself from this handle, otherwise you will have a loop forever. but anyway this is good to know, but I would say to you try to implement using the spring security roles, that will give you much more knowledge required in the marketing than doing this.